# Why does Path class allow file within a file?

Tags: java, path

I'm playing around with the NIO Path stuff, and came across this quesion:

What will the following code fragment print?

```
Path p1 = Paths.get("\\personal\\readme.txt");
Path p2 = Paths.get("\\index.html");
Path p3 = p1.relativize(p2);
System.out.println(p3);
```

The answer is

```
..\..\index.html
```

But this would make the entire Path:
\personal\readme.txt\index.html

This looks like nonsense to me, as you can't put a file within a file like this.  Can you?

If readme.txt were a directory instead of a file, I would be perfectly OK with this, but I'm very confused as to why it allows a filepath like this to exist?

Or is there some weird way that you can actually do this?

Comment: I would assume that the Path class makes no attempt to determine what type of file the path points to, or if the path points to anything at all. Performing the 'relativize' operation performs a simple text manipulation algorithm.

Comment: Yes so it seems, although I would have thought there would have been some sort of check on this?  Seems a strange thing to allow, and would seem to open a hole for exceptions..

Comment: There is nothing wrong with a folder named `readme.txt`.

Comment: _But this would make the entire Path: \personal\readme.txt\index.html_ That's not what that result means.

Comment: SLaks - Oh yes of course you are right. I thought of it only as a file, and therefore wondered why on earth they allowed this, even though Path is a String only and not the actual files, but of course what you say is perfectly true - a directory can be named in this way. D'oh!

Comment: SLaks - if you put your comment into an answer, I can "accept" it, as it totally answers my question.

Comment: @PenelopeTheDuck I think you've misunderstood the result of the `relativize` method. The fact that they are files or folders has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

The result is `..\..\index.html`

From the javadoc:

> This method attempts to construct a relative path that when resolved
>   against this path, yields a path that locates the same file as the
>   given path. For example, on UNIX, if this path is "/a/b" and the given
>   path is "/a/b/c/d" then the resulting relative path would be "c/d".
>   Where this path and the given path do not have a root component, then
>   a relative path can be constructed.

This means that you would have to go up two folders from this path to reach a path from which you can reach your given path, `index.html`.

Remember, these are all paths, not actual files/file descriptors.

```
Path p1 = Paths.get("\\personal\\readme.txt");
Path p2 = Paths.get("\\personal\\index.html");
Path p3 = p1.relativize(p2);
System.out.println(p3);
```

prints `..\index.html`, meaning from `\\personal\\readme.txt`, go up one and then access `index.html`.

Answer (score 0):

Both ISOs and Zip files (therefore JAR/WAR/XUL/CHM...) represent files that can contain a folder structure of files. These files can be handled either as a file, or as a folder; both are legitimate uses for them. Therefore, this would be semantically meaningful:

```
Path p1 = Paths.get("\\personal\\photos.zip");
Path p2 = Paths.get("\\family\\me.png");
Path p3 = p1.relativize(p2);
System.out.println(p3);"
```

While I am not aware of any implementations in Java that behave this way, it is a semantic used in XUL and Windows Explorer.